# Convert Expando Object based on runtime type?

Tags: generics, reflection, expandoobject

I have something like

```
Car:Vehicle {}   
Truck:Vehicle {}
```

Database ORM return list that could contain either.  Fetch < Vehicle > will lose sub class information.  If I fetch object or dynamic, it will return list of ExpandoObject.  Due the the underline framework restriction, I can't pass in generic T, only strings.  So I have something like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Car")
```

I can also create a typed List< Car > like so

```
var genericListType = typeof(List<>);
var specificListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(type);
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType) as IList;
```

Not sure where to go from here.  Reflection seems not very efficient, also can't add to IList.  Any hint?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the micro ORM I use, [schotime/NPoco](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco), has this built in

```
Type type = typeof(Vehicle).Assembly.GetType("Car");
var cars = db.Query<Vehicle>(
         new[] { type }, null, new Sql("select * from cars"));
```